# Javascript click event requires double clicks

Tags: javascript, click

I have a simple HTML-CSS-JavaScript page with an event listener on a button to toggle a div.

However, all is working but the animation function takes two clicks first time to work, although i consoled the click event to prove that the button listens to the first click too.

i tried to wrap into window.onload  but same thing.

note: i want to use pure javascript only.
thank you

this pic shows the first click (it says "clicked" in the console):

[image: After First Click]

this pic shows the second click (animation took place):

[image: After Second Click]

Here is my code:

```
            var showDivButton = document.getElementById('showDivButton');
            var info =  document.getElementById('info');

            showDivButton.addEventListener('click', animation) ;

            // animation func
            function animation () { 
                console.log('Clicked!');
                if (info.style.display === 'none'){
                    info.style.display =  'inline-block';
                    showDivButton.style.background = 'green';
                } else {
                     info.style.display =  'none';
                     showDivButton.style.background = 'gray';
                }

            }
```

Look at [My Plunker Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/vqZ7sHY1LkC17i11HDlT?p=preview) please. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to revise your function block as follow:

```
function animation () { 
    console.log('Clicked!');
    if (info.style.display == '' || info.style.display == 'none'){
        info.style.display =  'inline-block';
        showDivButton.style.background = 'green';
    } else {
         info.style.display =  'none';
         showDivButton.style.background = 'gray';
    }

}
```

`info.style.display` is `''` on initial

Comment: Ok, thanks,, why info.style.display is '' on initial if the style loads with the content even before js takes control?

Comment: and sorry what is the meaning of empty string? info.style.display == ''

Comment: @shireefkhatab That is because each element contains their default style which div's display is block (or inherit maybe), while the page is just loaded, these value would be undefined or simply an empty string until you assign a value to it.That is something like var a; console.log(a); the 'a' doesn't contains value until you assign one to it

Comment: The empty string is kinda like the 'default value' of info.style.display

Comment: Right, one more thing plz,, you are saying (while the page is just loaded, these value would be undefined or simply an empty string).. so what does the style shhet do ? and why is that div hidden ? isn`t because of the style effect?

Comment: @shireefkhatab Sorry I have missed a thing, the css should have nothing with your javascript object which the css control how to render elements and javascript object is a 'memory state' of objects

Answer (score 2):

Because `info.style.display` refers to the style **attribute** of your div, not the computed Style, so on the first click, this is not set.

You may want to look at [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), but i would advise switching class instead of directly modifying style.